# how to build Anti DNS Pinning (DNS rebinding) defence using Spring Security?

Tags: spring, security, dns, glassfish

Is it possible to protect web application against DNS rebinding attack using Spring Security? And how to configure Glassfish4.1 to protect server against same kind of attacks?
I've read that this could be resolved by blocking all http connections if Host header does not match DNS name of server, but could not find any piece of example code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, you can use a class which extends `javax.servlet.Filter` and there you can check the "Host" header manually, here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DNSHostFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String header = servletRequest.getHeader("Host");

        if (!header.contains(servletRequest.getLocalAddr())) {
            servletResponse.sendError(401);
        } else {
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

**Important:** You have to check if the method `servletRequest.getLocalAddr()` returns the correct IP of your server, otherwise you can just insert your IP as a string there (but that's not very flexible).

The example is pretty straight-forward, if the "Host" header doesn't contain your servers IP, then it'll respond with HTTP 401, otherwise the request is just normally executed.

Registering the filter in a normal JSF web application would work via `web.xml` like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>DNSHostFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.DNSHostFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DNSHostFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

In a Spring-based application it should be possible to register it like this in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean2() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new DNSHostFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");

    return registration;
}
```